# System requirement for rviz and gazebo and now ubuntu 11.04

Tags: gazebo, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok sorry for seemingly double posts --- but they r quite different questions -

1. is there some problem with ubuntu 11.04 not being able to support graphics card with optimus technology ??
2. Does 11.10 solve that problem and does ROS diamondback have a 11.10 repository?? :P
3. Thinking of buying a dell m14x(with nvidia GT555m card) - any idea if rviz and gazebo will work on it??
4. All dell laptops seem to have optimus (and are freaking costly) suggest any other good brand on which i can happily work with ros gazebo and rviz.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11200/system-requirement-for-rviz-and-gazebo-and-now-ubuntu-11.04/) by [Navam](https://answers.ros.org/users/1078/navam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2011-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. There is a problem with Optimus and Ubuntu at the moment. Some laptops allow you to subvert Optimus via the BIOS, but some don't. I've heard of some projects that attempt to fix these issues. I believe its called Bumblebee.
2. There's no officially supported 11.10 repo listed on the site. I can't imagine one will be made available until the official release of 11.10. Also, the Optimus problem is with the Nvidia drivers for Ubuntu in general, not 11.04 specifically.
3. I've read bad things about the Dell M14X on Ubuntu 11.04. You can do a quick search on Google to find out more, but I believe that Optimus is the main cause of the issue. After installing the Nvidia drivers, many people can't even boot back into Ubuntu at all.
4. As for brands, I'd look into Asus. We run all of our simulation and visualizations on an Asus G53J. It sports an Nvidia GeForce GTX 460M, and it works great. I've read that many high-end Lenovos run Optimus too, but I believe that they have a BIOS feature to disable the integrated card, and thus eliminate the problem (who needs an integrated card anyway?).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Navam](https://answers.ros.org/users/1078/navam/) on 2011-09-14**:
Thanks for the reply again :D ... yah i did a lot of searching regarding the above topic BUT the good news is i got it working on my chipset :D :D :D .... it was the awesome combination of 2.6.39 kernel + xorg's bleeding edge new test drivers for intel that support 3d rendering :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got optimus working with [ironhide for optimus](http://answers.ros.org/question/2258/how-to-make-use-of-the-nvidia-gpu-on-asus-1215n).  It's a cumbersome workaround, hopefully we get a real driver soon.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1